# highcharts 5.0.14 phantomjs issue with missing axis titles in exported image

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs, axis-labels, highcharts-convert

After upgrading to highcharts 5.0.14 the generated chart export image for my scatter charts is missing both axes titles.

I tried to see if the issue is with this version of highcharts. See jsfiddle using 5.0.14 libraries for my `type: 'scatter'` chart here: https://jsfiddle.net/17cyzvw9/1/

This returned correct chart image with proper axes titles.

[image]

I then tried with the highcharts export server at https://export.highcharts.com/, which is also generating a correct image intact with the chart axes titles.

I then executed the phantomjs command from a command window from my downloaded highchart library folder and I could see *the titles are missing*.

[image]

The phantomjs command to fetch output is like: `C:\Highstock\phantomjs\bin>phantomjs "C:\Highstock\highcharts-export-server-master\phantomjs\highcharts-convert.js" -infile C:\test.json -outfile C:\test.png`

`test.json` is same as used in the jsfiddle link above. 'test.png' is the output image as seen above.

What is going wrong here and where do I look to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you are using the legacy Java + PhantomJS Highcharts Export Server (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server). Instead, I recommend you to use the newer solution, Node.js-based export server (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server). With below command:

```
highcharts-export-server --infile options.json --outfile image.png
```

I was able to export chart to a PNG format without any problems (both titles are visible).

Comment: Yes you are right, am using the legacy Java + PhantomJS highcharts export server. Not sure if highcharts version 5.0.14 will be compatible with the new Node.js export server, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes, it will be. Upon installing you can choose desired version of Highcharts (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server -> see the Setup: Injecting the Highcharts dependency section).